# Sencha Touch 2.3 ( Unable to load data from a json file in sencha touch 2 )

Tags: sencha-touch-2, store, rss-reader, google-feed-api

I've trying to add parameter to url when Json store load but i'm taking this error that "Unable to load data." Here is the code of my store.

```
Ext.define('RssFeed.store.RssFeeds', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'RssFeed.model.RssFeed',
        'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json'
    ],

    config: {
        model: 'RssFeed.model.RssFeed',
        storeId: 'RssFeeds',
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'responseData.results'
            }
        }
    },

    searchFeed: function(request) {
        var request="turkey";
        Ext.getStore('RssFeeds').load({
            params: {
                q:request
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi your store seems correct and I tested it in my local machine.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.RssFeeds', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json'
    ],

    config: {
        //model: 'RssFeed.model.RssFeed',
        fields:['title'],
        storeId: 'RssFeeds',
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'responseData.results'
            }
        }
    },

    searchFeed: function(request) {
        request = request || '';
        Ext.getStore('RssFeeds').load({
            params: {
                q:request
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here's how I used it..

var store = Ext.create('MyApp.store.RssFeeds');
store.searchFeed('Philippines');